# License Check via Server and Server Manipulating

Tags: c#, localhost, wamp, licensing

I'm currently coding a commercial program in c# which checks if the license key is valid or not via server.

My question is (without giving any detail about process); is it good idea to check Host file if my root domain and ip address -which are for check the license key from server database- have added into the host file and if the addresses have added then delete them from the host file by programmatically? (or prefix # )

and also another check for wamp etc.. servers runs?

how can i avoid server manipulating ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the contents of C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, but that could be circumvented again, e.g. by setting up a custom DNS Server which will return a local-network IP adress for the dns-name of the activation server. In general, licensing-algorithms which will just consult a website if the key is valid or not will always be circumvented, because you can always decompile or disassemble the program to see what kind of response it awaits, and then construct your own spoofed activation server. Be especially aware of the decompilers which are in existence now, e.g. "Telerik JustDecompile" for any .NET assembly (this includes your C# program), which will also deobfuscate common obfuscators you might be using. That way, it might be especially easy to find out how your licensing algorithm works. In my opinion, public-key cryptography should be a good foundation for a secure licensing scheme, e.g. checking for a valid RSA signature on a signed activation key; but then again, licensing algorithms are a whole category of computer science for themselves.
So basically what I want to say is, that your licensing algorithm should be secure on its own, and should not rely on detecting wether there is any cracked activation server / debugger/ whatever running on the system.